# Extract json data in web page using pd.read_json()?

Tags: python, json, pandas, html-table

Trying to extract the table from this page "https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Statistics/Consolidated-Reports/Monthly-Bulletin?sc_lang=en#select1=0&select2=28". By inspect/network function of chorme, the data request link is "https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/stat/smstat/mthbull/rpt_turnover_short_selling_current_month_1910.json?_=1574650413485". This links looks like json format when access directly. However, the codes using this link does not work.

My codes:

```
import pandas as pd

url="https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/stat/smstat/mthbull/rpt_turnover_short_selling_current_month_1910.json?_=1574650413485"

df = pd.read_json(url)
print(df.info(verbose=True))
print(df)
```

also tried:

```
url="https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/stat/smstat/mthbull/rpt_turnover_short_selling_current_month_1910.json?"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try downloading the json first and then convert it back to `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

url='https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/stat/smstat/mthbull/rpt_turnover_short_selling_current_month_1910.json?_=1574650413485'

import urllib.request, json 
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as r:
    data = json.loads(r.read().decode())

df = pd.DataFrame(data['tables'][0]['body'])
columns = [item['text'] for item in data['tables'][0]['header']]
row_count = max(df['row'])
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.text.values.reshape((row_count,-1)),columns = columns)
```